# List of PyPI classifiers

Tags: python, pip, metadata, distutils, pypi

I can get a list of [trove classifiers](http://www.catb.org/~esr/trove/) like this:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://pypi.python.org/pypi', params={':action': 'list_classifiers'})
>>> classifiers = response.text.splitlines()
>>> len(classifiers)
649
>>> classifiers[:5]
['Development Status :: 1 - Planning',
 'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
 'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
 'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
 'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable']
```

Is there any way to get this list without using network access?  For example, does the list exist in distutils or something?  Where is the source of truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of truth is at PyPI only. Initially the list of classifiers was in [trove.py](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/blob/1509d429fb4f2991156928e3f6fc5da0c1ee2095/trove.py), but later moved to [SQL](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/blob/master/pkgbase_schema.sql#L730).

Answer (score 1):

Per [@phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671397/19651731), PyPI has the source of truth for trove classifiers. To add on, however, the package `trove-classifers` can list and confirm that a classifier exists.[1](https://pypi.org/project/trove-classifiers/) [2](https://github.com/pypa/trove-classifiers) Said package is maintained by the Python Package Authority[0](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html), and should be accurate.

Comment: @Azhar-Khan why was this edit necessary? It does not appear to add value to the question.